# QRect of full Virtual Desktop on Qt6

Tags: c++, qt, qt6

How to get `QRect` of a full Virtual Desktop?

For example, for putting a window on a whole Virtual Desktop (multimonitor system).

The obsolete Qt5 function is:

```
QApplication::desktop()->geometry()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
QRect desktopRect()
{
  QRegion virtualGeometry;
  for (auto screen : QGuiApplication::screens())
  {
    virtualGeometry += screen->geometry();
  }
  return virtualGeometry.boundingRect();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `PySide6` v6.4.0,

```py
QApplication.primaryScreen().virtualGeometry()
```

returns `PySide6.QtCore.QRect(-1920, 0, 3840, 1080)`.

I guess something similar can be done in Qt.

From [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qscreen.html#virtualGeometry-prop):

> `virtualGeometry : const QRect`
>
> This property holds the pixel geometry of the virtual desktop to which this screen belongs

Comment: `primaryScreen().virtualGeometry()` is coordinates of the primaryScreen, but not the full Virtual Desktop, that could include other screens. Do you have ultrawide 32:9 monitor?

Comment: @yalov no, I have two 1920x1080 screens next to each other. This is why I considered `primaryScreen().virtualGeometry()` to be the full virtual desktop.